# Unable to access Smartsheet using Python SDK

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

I'm running the following code to access Smartsheet using Python SDK

```
    access_token = 'XXXX'
    smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet(access_token)
    user_profile = smartsheet_client.Users.get_current_user()
    print(user_profile)
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 157, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "D:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 61, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
```

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

I'm using smartsheet-python-sdk.

I cannot run from work location

Answer (score 1):

If you are having connection errors from your work location you might have to use a proxy with the Smartsheet Python SDK to connect.

There is info on using a proxy with the Python SDK in the Advanced topics file in the GitHub repo here:
https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/blob/master/ADVANCED.md#http-proxy